# how can i exclude database from report pg_profile in DBMS postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to exclude some bases from the list so that only some of them are displayed in the report, and not the entire cluster

Answer (score 0):

Official support confirmed that it is impossible to explicitly specify specific bases. You can only disable the collection of statistics for specific databases